# Can't get function worker working - stops javascript running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm so close I can taste it. I've got my javascript working, but tried to put it in a function worker so that it is called every 5 seconds. When I tried to implement it, it stops working. I get no console errors and the text remains saying "Loading..."

```
<div id="number" style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600;">Loading...</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function worker() {
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'report.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
            $('#number').html(data.report.data[0].breakdown[0].counts)
            },
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(worker, 5000);
    }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Apparently it's valid javascript, and no console errors. So I don't know how to diagnose it.

Comment: You either need to invoke your IIFE, or remove it and call the function explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrapped your `worker` function inside an `expression`, however, you never  invoked it. You need to execute it.

```js
(function worker() {
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'report.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
            $('#number').html(data.report.data[0].breakdown[0].counts)
            },
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(worker, 5000);
    }
        });
    })(); // <!--- execute your function
```

```html
<div id="number" style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600;">Loading...</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```